# Should I get data from my database to create a dropdown list?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, database-management

I have a form with a dropdown selection whose option are determined from a table on a database. Periodically I will (manually) add more options to the dropdown and the database. Either I can make the dropdown selection get the options from the database like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, category FROM categories;";
    $result = $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $category = $row['category'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<option value='$id'>$category</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Which will give me less work because all I have to update now is the database and the form will update itself.

Or I can manually input the options into the form like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
    <option value='1'>option1</option>
    <option value='2'>option2</option>
    <option value='3'>option3</option>
</select>
```

This way will require more manual work but has the advantage of not having to connect to the database each time (less work for the servers).

My question is which method should I use? The method that gives me more work or the method that gives the server more work?

Comment: If you aleady have a database method working why would you go to the manual method. Stick with the database

Comment: Do it from the database. It's future proof. If you are going to use in another place the exact same categories, you will have only one place to manage them. If you are worried for the server load, then you can cache them in the session.

Comment: @RiggsFolly My concern is that the database method wastes system resources when I can easily (ish) do it manually and not have to waste resources every time the page loads

Comment: what're we talking "traffic/load wise", millions? MySQL/the server can handle a lot more than you think. Edit: If your table's not properly indexed, then yeah.. that will slow down a query.

Comment: @Fred I'm expecting very little traffic but I was wondering what the best practice is in general.

Comment: There isn't much I can add besides what the other guys said. Btw, I edited my comment above; you might want to take that into consideration (reload it).

Comment: actually keeping it in db is not best practice. see my answer

Comment: @ESDACIO44 forget about the fact that the db can handle it. this is not a valid argument to do the wrong thing. And this is not opinion based, is actually a fact. You don't get query the db unless you really need to - the case that you have some dynamic options that change a lot. Otherwise this is no brainer, it needs to be somewhere else than in the db.

Comment: You may also want to save the output as a file (here for the select-type, let's call it a cache html file). Next you can create a function that checks if cache exists - IF it exists, loads the content, ELSE creates them using database connection on the fly. And when you have to refresh the cache, simply delete those files (or entire folder) and let the function re-build the corresponding cache. I used this method for my dynamic menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are arguments pro and against using a database for select. As for the pro arguments, it is relatively easy to update - you just insert a new value and it will appear in your form. The problem with this approach is that your application will do a query each time that you render your form. In websites with millions of clicks this is not a good idea. So, the alternative used is that the query result is cached in some intermediary layer, especially when these values are not changing a lot. From my experience, the best way to handle these values is to load them from configuration files. These are values that rarely change and a new value can be added there. These can be still cached and a database hit is not required.

Comment: care to comment the negative vote?